# Separate function in R

Tags: r

I have a table B with a column X, that i want to split in 2 new columns y & z. However after running this command:

```
B %>%  separate(x, c("y", "z"), ", ", remove = FALSE)
```

I can't access the columns y and z via the regular `B$y` or `B$z` respectively.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you assigned the result (`<-`) to B again?

Comment: `B<-separate(x, c(y, z), ", ", remove = FALSE)` ?